# How to keep the screen in a fixed position when the keyboard is opened in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my log in screen attached below, I want **the view to stay fixed even when I open the keyboard**.

If you see [the screenshot of how my screen currently behaves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67vdF.jpg), you can notice that it gets scrolled up(pay attention to the Logo TextField) when the keyboard is opened.

I am currently using `SingleChildScrollView` to avoid overflow, but even if i do not use a `SingleChildScrollView`, the screen still repositions after opening the keyboard, only this time, with a pixel overflow.

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _logo(),
            LoginForm(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I keep the original positioning of the screen(as shown in the [screenshot on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67vdF.jpg)) even when the keyboard is opened?

**Edit:** Already tried `resizeToAvoidBottomInset`, it still scrolls.

Comment: Did you try removing SingleChildScrollView?

Comment: Yes I did, it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

In your Scaffold, try putting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property to "false".

Comment: It still scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your content in a `Scaffold` then set the property `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `false` so it will not resize your content when the device's Keyboard is shown. I've updated your code so you can use it.

```dart
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                _logo(),
                LoginForm(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The screen still scrolls. This version of the code(without SingleChildScrollView) scrolls as well:
`return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _logo(),
            LoginForm(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );`

Comment: Use `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` in the `Column` widget. Let me know if it fix the issue!